# perturbation theory solution of forced Duffing's equation

Tags: asymptotics, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

Question: Find the leading order of the asymptotic expansion for large t:
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt}+\varepsilon\beta\frac{dx}{dt}+x+\varepsilon x^3=F\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\bigl(1+\varepsilon\omega\bigr)t\Bigr)
$$

I have tried to solve the problem via regular multiple scale analysis by transforming
$t_0=t$, $t_1=\varepsilon t$ & expressing the solution in the form of an asymptotic expansion $$x(t)=y(t_0,t_1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varepsilon^ny_n(t_0,t_1).$$

The leading order problem becomes:
$$
\frac{\partial^2y_0}{\partial t_0}+y_0=F\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1)\Bigr)
$$
solving, i obtain
$$y_0=R_0(t_1)\cos(t_0+\phi_0(t_1))+\frac{9}{8}\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1)\Bigr)$$

After solving the leading order the 1st order problem is as follows
$$\small\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 y_1}{\partial t_0}+y_1
&=\sin(t_0+\phi_0)(2R_0'+\beta R_0)+\cos(t_0+\phi_0)(2R_0\phi_0')
\\&~~~+\frac{\omega}{4}F\cos(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1))
+\frac{3}{8}\beta F\sin(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1))
\\&~~~-R_0^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos(3(t_0+\phi_0)))
+\frac{3}{4}\cos((t_0+\omega t_1))\right)
\\&~~~-(\frac{9}{8}F)^3(\frac{1}{4}\cos(t_0+\omega t_1)
+\frac{3}{4}\cos(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1)))
\\&~~~-3R_0(\frac{9}{8}F)^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos\big(\frac{1}{3}t_0+\phi_0-\frac{2}{3}(\omega t_1)\big)
+\frac{1}{4}\cos(\frac{4}{3}t_0+\phi_i+\frac{2}{3}\omega t_1)
+\frac{1}{2}\cos(t_0 +\phi_0)\right)
\\&~~~-3R_0^2(\frac{9}{8}F)\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos(\frac{5}{2}t_0+2\phi_0+\frac{1}{3}\omega t_1)+\frac{1}{4}\cos(\frac{3}{2}t_0+2\phi_0-\frac{1}{3}\omega t_1)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega_1 t_1))\right)
\end{align}$$
demanding the coefficent of the $\sin(t_0+\phi_0)$ term to vanish (for large $t$)
i obtain $R_0=0$, thus the equation becomes
$$\small\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 y_1}{\partial t_0}+y_1
&=\frac{\omega}{4}F\cos(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1))+\frac{3}{8}\beta F\sin(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1))
\\&~~~-(\frac{9}{8}F)^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos(t_0+\omega t_1)+\frac{3}{4}\cos(\frac{1}{3}(t_0+\omega t_1)))\right)
\end{align}$$
the problem is that a secular term remains (i.e. $-(\frac{9}{8}F)^3(\frac{1}{4}\cos(t_0+\omega t_1))$)?

Comment: $t$ or $x$? Also the forcing term on the hrs should have the independent variable no?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, i've corrected any missunderstanding and written my approach for solving, and what problem i have encounter. thanks for the help